# How can I get backward window cycling (cmd-shift-`) to work with Emacs.app?

Tags: macos, emacs

Cmd-` works fine, but when I try cmd-shift-`, I get the message, "s-~ is undefined."

Comment: This is not programming related.

Comment: It belongs over on superuser.com, people will move it there for you. (please add your close / move vote guys)

Comment: To the extent that Emacs has to be programmed in order to change its behavior even quite trivially, I disagree. These kinds of questions look like simple usage queries, but the answers almost always relate to emacs lisp programming, and understanding how the editor itself is built.

Comment: SO also has 10x as many posts tagged emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-~") 'ns-prev-frame)
```